# Solution to $\ddot{u}+u=-2A\cos(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation
$$\ddot{u}+u=-2A\cos(t),\quad u(0)=0,\quad \dot{u}(0)=0$$
with $\ddot{u}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}u$.

I know that $u(t)=-At\sin(t)$
solves the equation, but I am having a hard time finding the solution. I tried following:

The differential equation is equivalent to the second equation of the following non-homogeneous linear system

$$\dot{y}=\begin{pmatrix}0& 1\\ -1 &0\end{pmatrix}y+\begin{pmatrix}0\\ -2A\cos(t)\end{pmatrix}=:Ay+b(t)$$

A fundamental solution system for the homogeneous system is for example

$$\Phi(t)=\pmatrix{\cos(t) &\sin(t)\\ \sin(t) &-\cos(t)}$$
with $\Phi(t)=\Phi(t)^{-1}$. Then there is a special solution
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Psi(t)&=\Phi(t)\int_{0}^t\Phi(s)^{-1}b(s)ds.
\end{aligned}$$

I tried to compute it, but there must be an error. I did following:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^t\Phi(s)^{-1}b(s)ds&=\int_{0}^t\pmatrix{\cos(s) &\sin(s)\\ \sin(s) &-\cos(s)}\begin{pmatrix}0\\ -2A\cos(s)\end{pmatrix}ds\\
&=\int_{0}^t\begin{pmatrix}-2A\cos(s)\sin(s)\\ 2A\cos(s)\cos(s)\end{pmatrix}ds\\
&=\pmatrix{A\cos^2(t) \\ At+A\sin(t)\cos(t)}
\end{aligned}$$

This should give me the solution
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Psi(t)&=\pmatrix{\cos(t) &\sin(t)\\ \sin(t) &-\cos(t)}\pmatrix{A\cos^2(t) \\ At+A\sin(t)\cos(t)}\\
&=\pmatrix{ A\cos^2(t)\cos(t)+At\sin(t)+A\sin^2(t)\cos(t) \\ \ldots}\\
&=\pmatrix{ A\cos(t)+At\sin(t) \\ \ldots}\\
\end{aligned}$$

However
$$A \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}(\cos(t)+t\sin(t))+A\cos(t)+At\sin(t)=2A\cos(t)$$
instead of $$-2A\cos(t).$$

I cannot find my mistake. What did I do wrong?

**EDIT:** The fundamental system was wrong. It is clearly not a fundamental system, since $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\cos(t) = -\sin(t)\ne \sin(t)$. Instead, the choice
$$\Phi(t)=\Phi(t)^{-1}=\pmatrix{\sin(t) & \cos(t)\\ \cos(t) & -\sin(t)}$$
leads to

$$\int_{0}^t\Phi(s)^{-1}b(s)ds=\pmatrix{-At-A\sin(t)\cos(t) \\ A\sin^2(t)}$$
such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Psi(t)=\Phi(t)\int_{0}^t\Phi(s)^{-1}b(s)ds&=\pmatrix{\sin(t) & \cos(t)\\ \cos(t) & -\sin(t)}\pmatrix{-At-A\sin(t)\cos(t) \\ A\sin^2(t)}\\
&=\pmatrix{-At\sin(t) \\ -A\sin(t)-At\cos(t)}
\end{aligned}$$

Now, one can see that $\Psi_2=\dot{\Psi_1}$, such that the second row of
$\dot{\Psi}=A\Psi+b(t)$ reads as
$$\ddot{\Psi_1}+\Psi_1=-2A\cos(t),$$
i.e. $\Psi_1$ solves the original differential equation.

Comment: Oh, that fundamental system is probably wrong...

Comment: You mean even in the EDIT? I think it is correct now, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, right, thank you! Everything should be looking nice, now. :-)

Comment: Yes, now it is correct. It seems often miraculous how the integration first produces extensive expressions that then in the combination partially cancel and reduce to something sane.

Comment: Actually, I am wondering now, if I have to check, that $\Psi_2=\dot{\Psi_1}$ holds true. Is $\Psi_2=\dot{\Psi_1}$ really necessary for the solution $\Psi(t)$ of $\dot{y}=Ay+b(t)$? Or is it only sufficient? (If $\Psi_2=\dot{\Psi_1}$ is true, the second row of $\dot{y}=Ay+b(t)$ clearly translates to $\ddot{\Psi_1}+\Psi_1=-2A\cos(t)$.)

Comment: It should always automatically be true, as the convention for the state is to have components $\pmatrix{y\\y'}$. But you can take it as a test for the correctness of your computations. If it is not true, then there is some slight error somewhere. If it holds true, then the result could still be wrong, but most assuredly the error behind that will be deeper, systematic, conceptual or so.